# celery max retries on signature set isn't updated

Tags: python, celery, signature

**Hey :)**

So I encountered a bug in my code and while trying to solve it -  I wrote this little celery task:

```
@shared_task(bind=True, name='sometask', autoretry_for=(Exception,), default_retry_delay=1)
def sometask(self, items, *args, **kwargs):
    print(self.max_retries)
    raise Exception
```

and I tried to override the retries by envoking set() on the signature :

```
s = sometask.s(items=[]).set(max_retries=200, countdown=1)
s()
```

when I checked the output I could see that what was printed is 3 - the default max retries in celery. and not my 200..

Can anyone tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong?

I need to override the max retries and that seemed to be my only option , but it doesn't work as I expected.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2):

Although the docs say that [`retry_policy`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.0.2/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) is a valid option to pass to `apply_async`, it appears to be the retry policy to *publish* a task, not for the task itself to retry.

In addition, `max_retries` for the task does not appear to be mutable at runtime. However, it can be set in the decorator: `@shared_task(bind=True, name='sometask', autoretry_for=(Exception,), default_retry_delay=1, max_retries=200)`.

I can upon this when trying to change the max_retries at run time which doesn't seem possible, [this issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4383), non-withstanding. One workaround:

```py
@shared_task(bind=True, max_retries=200)
def sometask(self, items, *args, **kwargs):
    print(self.max_retries)
    raise Exception

# only want to retry normal 3 times here
sometask.apply_async(retries=sometask.max_retries - 3)
```